# python matrix traversal expanding outwards concentric squares

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a 5x5 matrix as follows:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Based on some location, I am given an index in both the (x,y) coordinate where I want to start building concentric squares outwards of values. A few examples below:

```
3 3 3 3 3
3 2 2 2 2
3 2 1 1 2
3 2 1 1 2
3 2 2 2 2
```

```
2 2 2 3 4
1 1 2 3 4
1 1 2 3 4
2 2 2 3 4
3 3 3 3 4
```

Is there a more automated / function / libraries that can do this easily instead of hard-coding these sort of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of the exact logic, but assuming `x`, `y` the coordinates of the top left corner of the square of 1s, you could craft a vertical and horizontal array with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and combine them with broadcasting and [`numpy.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
x, y = 2, 2
N = 5

Xs = np.arange(N)-x
Ys = np.arange(N)-y

out = np.maximum(np.where(Xs>0, Xs, 1-Xs)[:, None],
                 np.where(Ys>0, Ys, 1-Ys)
                )
```

Output:

```
array([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 2, 1, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 1, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
```

Output for `x = 1 ; y = 0 ; N = 6`:

```
array([[2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]])
```

Intermediates (`x = 5 ; y = 5 ; N = 5`):

```
# Xs
array([-2, -1,  0,  1,  2])

# np.where(Xs>0, Xs, 1-Xs)[:, None]
array([[3],
       [2],
       [1],
       [1],
       [2]])

# Ys
array([-2, -1,  0,  1,  2])

# np.where(Ys>0, Ys, 1-Ys)
array([3, 2, 1, 1, 2])
```

Comment: This looks great. I should have mentioned in the original post, but is there a way to stop at a certain number? For example, if I still had the 5x5 grid, but only build the concentric squares out to number 2, or 3, etc.?

Comment: I imagine you can [`clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) the intermediate arrays, or the output.